# no matching function call error using std::find

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I have the following function (for testing):

```
static bool foo(void)
{
  std::string name = "name";
  std::vector<std::string> test;
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator vStart = test.begin();
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator vEnd = test.end();
  return (std::find(vStart, vEnd, name) == vEnd);
}
```

And I get a compilation error:

```
/data/src/fiware-orion/src/lib/common/string.cpp: In function 'bool foo()':
/data/src/fiware-orion/src/lib/common/string.cpp:167:39: error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator&, std::string&)'
   return (std::find(vStart, vEnd, name) == vEnd);
                                       ^
/data/src/fiware-orion/src/lib/common/string.cpp:167:39: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_facets.h:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/sstream:38,
                 from /data/src/fiware-orion/src/lib/common/string.cpp:31:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:369:5: note: template<class _CharT2> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_CharT2>::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, const _CharT2&)
     find(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __first,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:369:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/data/src/fiware-orion/src/lib/common/string.cpp:167:39: note:   '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >' is not derived from 'std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>'
   return (std::find(vStart, vEnd, name) == vEnd);
```

Maybe the message which points to the problem is this:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

but as far as I undersand the concrete classes used in the find() function argument (`std::vector<std::string>::iterator`, `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` and `std::string`) are clear.

What's specially surprises me is that this same code fragment for foo() function is working verbatim in other parts of my code (i.e. other .cpp files) so maybe it is related somehow with the `#include` chain in a way I'm not able to deduce or trace...

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `find` from `#include <algorithm>` in the error message, only the one from `streambuf_iterator.h`. Add `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The error text wasn't very clear... :)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an iterator, but your function declaration is 'void'

Comment: You are right. It seems the compilation error about "not matching function" maskes the one about wrong return in the function. However, I have updated the question post to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to include `<algorithm>`

Please add this `#include <algorithm>`